# How to position overlay above the photo?

Tags: css

I am trying to make the overlap appear on top of the photo instead of under it. Here is a link to my test page - http://kaniamea.com/image.htm
How can I position this correctly and be responsive in the same time?
And here is the code:

```
<div align="center">
<div class="image-container"> <a href="link"><img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/activities/oahu_dinner.jpg" height="174" width="231">
  <div class="after">This is some content</div>
  </a> </div>
<div class="image-container"> <a href="link"><img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/activities/oahu_dinner.jpg" height="174" width="231">
  <div class="after">This is some content</div>
  </a> </div>
<div class="image-container"> <a href="link"><img src="https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/images/activities/oahu_dinner.jpg" height="174" width="231">
  <div class="after">This is some content</div>
  </a> </div>
<style>

.image-container {
    width:230px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:4px;
}

.image-container .after {
    width:230px;
    height:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:4px;
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
    color: #FFF;
}
.image-container:hover .after {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
}

</style>
```

Comment: `margin-top:-175px;` on `.after` should be fine given that your images have fixed dimensions.

Comment: Thank you, Alexei! This is very helpful!